# How to Create a float-like button in app ( make a hole in the layout )?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can i create in layout that can let me show and click on a button below it.
Like i have a float button in-app.

Or

To use it for interactive mode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.

[image]

[Solution]

```
    Positioned.fill(
      child: ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
          Colors.black,
          BlendMode.srcOut,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 9,
                  bottom: 27,
                ),
                width: 70,
                height: 70,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```